# Where to store dictionary in Django

Tags: python, django, web, backend

I have a dictionary that I get from the local delivery company API. I want to use it in my app to populate the city select field. I don't want to get this data every time when a user loads the page. So I need to store it somewhere and update it once a day. What is the best way to do this using Django?

```
url = 'https://api.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/json/'
data = {
    "apiKey": "apiKey",
    "modelName": "Address",
    "calledMethod": "getCities",
    "methodProperties": {}
}
city_list_json = requests.post(url, json=data).text
city_dict = {d['Ref']: d['Description'] for d in json.loads(city_list_json)['data']}
```

UPD: the question is more about what is the proper way to store this dictionary in db? I need to create a model in models.py or there are other ways? Sorry, if my question sounds stupid, this is my first question on this website:)

Comment: There are many possible options and I'd guess this is going to be opinion based. I'd say Redis is a reasonable alternative

Answer (score 0):

A normal Django model without a JSON field could handle this perfectly fine. It would also give you the record of previous days' information. Your business logic dictates how often to call the API. Your options would be to either:

1. Setup a background task to grab the API data once a day at midnight (or whenever); or
2. Have a 'last_updated' field on your model which every request checks, if it's been >24 hours then that request triggers the API call

Option 2 is easier to implement but the downside is that if the API call is slow then whoever makes that request is going to be in for a wait before the page loads

Comment: can you please send some code for the first option? I'm new to programming and don't really understand where in the django project I need to set this up

Comment: https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/